# OnInit method not getting called when I navigate to url in ngZone

Tags: angular

I have two components and I am trying to navigate to URL in NgZone method. But issue that I am facing is OnInit method is not getting called when I navigate. Below id the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._zone.run(() => {
        window['navigate'] = () => {
          this.route.navigate(['/users'];
        };
    });
  }
```

Using above code I am able to navigate to /users URL. But `UsersComponent` `onInit()` method is not getting called on navigation.

I have looked for the solution and it seems like in ngZone I am navigating out of angular scope. So I tried using `ChangeDetectorRef` but its not working as I am navigating away from URL.
Please let me know if my understanding is correct and suggest me possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the router.navigate() into a separate "Zone":

import:

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
```

inject:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { ... }
```

apply:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["/users"]);
});
```

Comment: Yup.. Quick hack.. Thanks!